# Geometry Shader example code not working from Opengl Superbible

Tags: opengl, geometry-shader

I am reading the OpenGL Superbible 7th edition. It is a great book and all, but when I get to the Geometry Shader part of the book, the program stops working.

Some things that happen:
Whenever I don't render with the Geometry Shader, all of the other Shader things work with the past example. And when I take out `glVertexAttrib4fv();`, and I keep the geometry shader is rendered, it only renders one point. Please help. (I am using `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,3);`)

```
#version 410 core

layout(triangles) in;
layout(points, max_vertices = 3) out;

void main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length();i++)
    {
        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        EmitVertex();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote from the documentation and highlight the important parts in bold.

> **The input_primitive​ type must match the primitive type** for the vertex
>   stream provided to the GS. If Tessellation is enabled, then the
>   primitive type is specified by the Tessellation Evaluation Shader's
>   output qualifiers. **If Tessellation is not enabled, then the primitive
>   type is provided by the drawing command that renders with this shader
>   program.**

Meaning the input primitive type in the geometry shader should match the type given to the draw command glDrawArrays().

Here is the matching list, check the documentation: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader

```
GEOMETRY INPUT: points  
DRAW COMMAND: GL_POINTS  
NUMBER OF VERTICES: 1   

GEOMETRY INPUT: lines  
DRAW COMMAND: GL_LINES or GL_LINE_STRIP or GL_LINE_LIST  
NUMBER OF VERTICES: 2

GEOMETRY INPUT: triangles  
DRAW COMMAND: GL_TRIANGLES or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP or GL_TRIANGLE_FAN  
NUMBER OF VERTICES: 3
```

Where number of vertices is the number of vertices received per input primitive to the geometry shader.

Comment: No, I meant for it to be like this photo (scroll down to the bottom and you will find the photo) :http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2429029&seqNum=4. I already have a tessellated triangle, I just need it to be changed by a geometry shader as the photo shows.  To find how it looks without the geometry shader (in my code) look here :http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2429029&seqNum=3

Comment: render method: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ik12fw22s4iqun/render.txt?dl=0